Help me understand if this BJT are in saturation, cut-off mode or none
I am currently studying the bypass circuit of the tube screamer guitar pedal. The part of the circuit i am initially having problems with is the following (image taken from https://www.electrosmash.com/tube-screamer-analysis):

The first thing i need to look at, is how the transistor Q5 and Q6 start when the power is turned on. My theory is the following, feel free to correct me:
When the power is turned on, one of the two transistors will have a very small current ICQ flowing through, since the resistance in the collector is so big. This will force the transistor into saturation mode, and all 9 volts will drop in the resistance. Since the collector of that transistor is connected to the base of the other, the voltage applied at that base will be 0 volts, forcing that transistor into cut-off mode. This has the opposite effect, VCEQ of that transistor will be the entire 9 volts, and the voltage in the collector of that transistor will be also 9 volts.
I suppose my theory is at least partially incorrect, i am quite new to transistors in general, and i studied them as amplifiers.
Once i understand this, i will follow up in another post probably asking about how the rest of the circuit works!

What are the voltages of the base, emitter, and collector for each transistor?

It doesn't [work]: Q7's Vbe shorts out Q6 C-E, ensuring Q5 never turns on, and the flip doesn't flop.
Possibly Q7 is a 2N7000 or such by mistake, and not labeled as such; or the author forgot to draw more resistors going to it.
Otherwise, for a flip-flop circuit without this loading error, your general approach is correct.  What's missing is just a bit more nuance on how it gets there.
Suppose we raise the supply voltage gradually from zero.  At first, all node voltages are zero and the transistors are off.
By about 1.4V (or with D6 + R29 here for some reason, more like 2V), the transistors start to turn on, and then your Icq assumption applies.
Note that, in absence of any perturbation, this is a solution to the operating conditions: both Vce's can be equal, and outside of saturation.  Loop gain will be very high (gm ≈ Ic / Vth), but there is still a single point where steady operation can occur.
Indeed, circuits like this can be tricky to simulate, because components are perfectly matched unless otherwise specified -- and SPICE and other simulators are happy to round off errors that would otherwise perturb the circuit.  If we didn't specify resistors as such round numbers as "56000" and instead used realistic ones like "55943.71" and "56018.72" (and, importantly, unique such values for each resistor, and dimensions or other parameters for each transistor, etc.), this is avoided -- or a dynamic solution can be employed, like introducing a noise source or voltage step to the feedback loop.
Anyway, about that feedback, let's apply the feedback condition.  Note that, if one transistor were to turn on ever-so-slightly more than the other, the other would be turned off slightly, which would turn the one on more... and so on.  Loop gain is high, meaning the updated change, from an initial change, is large (~hundreds?).  This is positive feedback, a regenerative loop that compounds on itself.  This doesn't go forever of course, and after an initial exponential-growth phase, eventually one transistor races towards cutoff, and the other saturation.
What we have is an unstable dynamic system, like a ball perched on top of a hill.  Any perturbation puts the ball in motion, and it rolls inexorably downward -- though to which direction, depends on that initial kick.  If the kick is random, or due to random variation in component values, we cannot predict the final position -- and equally so, the flip-flop startup state.
As a dynamical system, this compounding evolves over time.  The rate at which it diverges (heads towards cutoff/saturation) depends on the time constant of the circuit, which here will be more or less the RC time constant given by the transistor capacitances and resistors connecting them.  For 2SC1815 as shown, this is some 5-10pF, so with the about 30k Thevenin equivalent resistance, it will take some 300s of ns to stabilize.  Which is pretty quick, but also easily observed on the oscilloscope -- and indeed, in such circuits, we find rise/fall times of 100s of ns typically.
